# Vue.js prop is always undefined, shows up in Vue devtools

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an image component that looks like the below:

```
<template>
    <div :class="wrapperClasses" class="v-image">
        <div class="holder">
            <img :src="imgUrl" alt="" :class="imgClasses">
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    image: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    divClasses: {
      default: ""
    },
    imgClasses: {
      default: ""
    }
  },
  computed: {
    wrapperClasses() {
      let c = [this.divClasses];
      c.push("aspect-ratio-goes-here");
      return c.join(" ");
    },
    imgUrl() {
      if (this.image) {
        return image.url;
      }
      return "http://via.placeholder.com/600x800?text=Image+coming+soon";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I then use it like this:

```
<v-image 
   :image='{
    "id":1,
    "model_id":1,
    "collection_name":"photos",
    "name":"medialibrary073ZM0",
    "file_name":"medialibrary073zm0.jpg",
    "mime_type":"image\/jpeg",
    "disk":"public",
    "size":53946,
    "manipulations":[],
    "custom_properties":{"primaryColor":"red"},
    "responsive_images":[],
    "order_column":1,
    "created_at":"2018-04-18 10:48:11",
    "updated_at":"2018-04-18 10:48:11",
    "url":"\/storage\/1\/medialibrary073zm0.jpg"
  }'>
</v-image>
```

So all looks good. But in my console I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: image is not defined"

found in

---> <VImage> at resources/assets/js/components/VImage.vue
       <Root>
```

If I take a look at my vue dev tools I get the following:

[image: Dev tools shows prop is correctly found]

What is going on? Why is the prop not defined?

#### Demo

**https://codesandbox.io/s/j2v7zkn203**

Comment: what prop isn't defined?

Comment: "ReferenceError: image is not defined" – image... except it is defined in dev tools...

Comment: maybe recreate the problem if you can https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @A.Lau good idea! https://codesandbox.io/s/j2v7zkn203

Comment: this line `return image.url;` should be this `return this.image.url;` Just forgot the `this` Much easier to find the problem when it gives you the line error.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for helping me. I'm so stupid.

Comment: Do you want to add an answer for the reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a simple mistake.

```
imgUrl() {
  if (this.image) {
    return image.url;
  }
  return "http://via.placeholder.com/600x800?text=Image+coming+soon";
}
```

should have been

```
imgUrl() {
  if (this.image) {
    return this.image.url;
  }
  return "http://via.placeholder.com/600x800?text=Image+coming+soon";
}
```

Just missing the `this`.

Also, for vue stuff, it's much easier to debug when you get line errors :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue